# bash passing executable argument to function

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash and I cannot figure out how to pass the result of this to a function. I have a file that looks like:

```
1  df sadsd csd c
2  wkdfgc sdkj ds 
3 sdjcvh sdch vsd h
4 sjdch sdhc sd
```

and I have a function that looks like

```
SimpleFunction () {
> echo $1;
> echo $2;
> }
```

and I am trying to do something like:

```
SimpleFunction $( cat myfile | grep -i "2") ": line 2"
```

and I am expecting an output that looks like

```
2  wkdfgc sdkj ds 
: line2
```

but I get

```
2
wkdfgc
```

How can I get my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because args are by default seperated by space. You can bypass this by double quoting args:

```
SimpleFunction "$( cat myfile | grep -i '2')" ": line 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The cat/grep command's output is the whole line `2  wkdfgc sdkj ds` so when this string is passed to SimpleFunction, `2` is the first parameter, `wkdfgc` is the second parameter and so on.

When you `echo $1` and `echo $2`, you're printing the first two parameters. If you want to print the whole line, do `echo $*`